# Hover on Table Data

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have a html table in which some cells are empty and some cells have data.
When I do hover on the cells that have data,the background colour should change black and cursor should be pointed. If there are no data in the cell or if the cell is blank,there should be no hover applied on the cell and mouse pointer should be normal.

Comment: Do you have any starter code? or are you trying to get us to write everything for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use pure css - depends what browsers you are supporting:

```
table td:hover:not(:empty) {
    background: red;
}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/h1g8cLp5/)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').on('mouseover', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var self=$(this);
        var x=$.trim(self.text());
        $('td').css({
            'cursor':'default',
            'background-color': 'white'
        });
        if(x==''){
            self.css({
                'cursor':'default',
                'background-color': 'white'
            });
        }else{
            self.css({
                'cursor':'pointer',
                'background-color': 'red'

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also try this one

```
$query = mysql_query(Select * from tablename);
<table>
While( $test = mysq_fetch_array($query))

{
if($test['columnname'] !='')
{
$color = "has_content";
}
else
$color = "no_content";

echo "<td class='$color' >content...</td>";

}
</table>
```

these use these below CSS

```
 .has_content
    {
 background-color:black; 
}
    .no_content
    {
 background-color:white;
 }
    .has_content:hover
    { 
cursor:pointer;
}
```